# How is a REST response content "magically" converted from 'list' to 'string'

Tags: python, rest

```
>>> print type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> response.content = a
>>> print type(response.content)
<type 'str'>
```

Could you explain me this "magic?" How is `a` converted from `list` to `string`?

`response` is an instance of `rest_framework.response.Response`.

Comment: What does `some_object.some_variable` have to do with `some_variable`?  Could you explain this a little better?

Comment: the `type()` function returns a string, nothing is converted.

Comment: Which magic caused `some_object` to appear unbidden?

Comment: I assigned list value to response.content variable and I get ... string. How? Why?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen can you explain `print type([])` using the same argument?

Comment: content is property of the request class and can be implemented to return whatever it wants... https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L282

Comment: Now that the question has been edited to make it more clear, I've upvoted.  Thank you @TomCruise for making your question more clear and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that this class makes this conversion by means of defining `__setattr__` method. You can read http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access for more information.

Comment: Oh, right.  I suppose there are 2 ways.  `__setattr__` (possibly with a `__getattr__`)/`__getattribute__` or descriptors.

Answer (score 8):

There are only a couple ways that you could have something like this happen.  The most common reason is if `response.content` is implemented as some sort of descriptor, interesting things like this could happen.  (The typical descriptor which would operate like this would be a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) object).  In this case, the property's getter would be returning a string.  As a formal example:

```
class Foo(self):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 1

    @property
    def attribute_like(self):
        return str(self._x)

    @attribute_like.setter
    def attribute_like(self,value):
        self._x = value

f = Foo()
f.attribute_like = [1,2,3]
print type(f.attribute_like)
```

Comment: @dm03514 -- Well, I suppose that answers it then. :)